# How do I count how many times an ibaction is performed?

Tags: ios, ibaction

I am about to release an iPhone app for a small business. The app has a call button which calls the business with an ibaction. I would like to know if i can find out how many times this action occurs so i can get a better idea of how effective the app is, and how to go about it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You will need some kind analytics, like [Google analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/), [flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) and many more.

Comment: Site Catalyst is also a valid approach.  These frameworks have a lot to offer, so you could track a lot more about your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a web-service with a simple method which will increment a counter on a server. And call it asynchronously every time user taps a button. I would do it like this:

```
#define TAP_COUNT_KEY @"tapcnt"
#define MAKE_URL(X) [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://my_service_address?cnt=%d", X]]

dispatch_queue_t serviceQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Tap counter queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(serviceQueue, ^{
    NSUInteger counter = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:TAP_COUNT_KEY] + 1;

    NSURL *serviceUrl = MAKE_URL(counter);
    NSError *error = nil;
    [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:serviceUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    else
        counter = 0;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:counter forKey:TAP_COUNT_KEY];
});
dispatch_release(serviceQueue);
```

Answer (score 1):

On IBAction method, you can increment counter by +1. Then you can store it into `NSUserDefaults` by key-value pair. And every time, increase counter and store it. So it'll maintain counter state until application will be uninstalled.

```
int counter;

-(IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
     NSUserDefaults *_countDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     counter = [[_countDefaults integerForKey:@"Counter"] intValue];
     counter++;

     [_countDefaults setInteger:counter forKey:@"Counter"];
     [_countDefaults synchronize];       
}
```

Hopefully, you'll get idea.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to declare `counter` as a global, file-scoped variable. There is also no need to send `-[NSUserDefaults synchronize]`. And you shouldn’t use `-setValue:forKey:` in this case since `NSUserDefaults` provides support for integers: use `-[NSUserDefaults integerForKey:]` and `-[NSUserDefaults setInteger:forKey:]` instead. Furthermore, this does not solve the problem of sending this information to the developer in a per user basis.

Comment: @Bavarious Okay. Thanks mate, just forgot -[NSUserDefaults integerForKey:] method. I've suggested because he wants to maintain counter clicks. Anyways thanks for correcting me..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can increase your button tag value and access it where ever you want,

```
-(IBAction)btnPanic:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
    btn.tag=btn.tag+1;
}
```

Comment: There is a nice article explaining why you should not play with tags. http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-4-uiview.html